# How do I call a C++ function from .net passing a 2D array?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-c++, pinvoke

I am trying to call the method with the following declaration:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall CalcDDtable(struct ddTableDeal tableDeal, struct ddTableResults * tablep);
```

The structs are defined thus:

```
    struct ddTableDeal {
  unsigned int cards[4][4];
};

struct ddTableResults {
  int resTable[5][4];
};
```

I am trying to call it thus:

```vb
  <DllImport("dds.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Shared Function CalcDDtable(ByVal deal As TableDeal, ByRef results As TableResults) As Integer
End Function

Public Function CalculateDeal() As Integer
    Dim tableDeal As TableDeal
    Dim tableResults As TableResults
    Dim cards(3, 3) As Integer
    cards(0, 0) = 32764
    cards(1, 1) = 32764
    cards(2, 2) = 32764
    cards(3, 3) = 32764
    tableDeal.Cards = cards

    Dim results(4, 3) As Integer
    tableResults=new TableResults
    tableResults.Results = results

    Dim errorCode = CalcDDtable(tableDeal, tableResults)

    Return errorCode
End Function

End Class

Public Structure TableDeal
    Dim Cards(,) As Integer
End Structure

Public Structure TableResults
    Dim Results(,) As Integer
End Structure
```

The structs should both be twodimensional arrays with indexes of 4,4 and 5,4 respectively. The second one is an out parameter.

Where am I going wrong?

For those who want to know:this is the [double dummy solver .dll](http://privat.bahnhof.se/wb758135/) written by Bo Haglund

Comment: Please give the C++ declaration of the two structs. Also why are you writing `Dim results(4, 4)` if the dimensions are (5, 4)?

Comment: @ David Heffernan: I edited the question.

Comment: Does your code really set tableResults.Results to point to the results array and _then_ set tableResults to point to a new Tableresults instance?  You'll pass a reference with Results set to nothing if you do that.

Comment: @ Frank Boyne: No I wasn't, was I? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/cc417b5e-38f7-424b-925a-d999df90ae29)